# Identify round RS485 connector

Tags: identification, connector, rs485, solar-energy

I'm going to get a solar inverter. It has a RS485 port on a round waterproof male [connector](https://alphyraz.tweakblogs.net/blog/17760/solis-omvormer-uitlezen-met-een-raspberry-pi):

[image]

The diameter of the mating female connector shell seems to be about the same as a MC4, or 19mm.

[image]

I'm looking for a female connector to mate with it. Here's an [example](https://solarandheatstore.com/product/solis-485-cable-loom-for-data-logging-box/):

[image]

A [wifi dongle](https://www.puntoenergiashop.it/fr/solis/cl%C3%A9-wifi-dongle-pour-la-connexion-et-la-surveillance-de-l-onduleur-solis.html) can also be plugged in the RS485 port, this provides a better view of the connector I want.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: A Hirose HR10 maybe?

Comment: @DanSheppard the tabs are different

Comment: Looks like any old circular M8 connector. You'll have to figure out which type. See lists e.g. here: https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/circular-connectors/intersection/m8m12.html?tab=pgp-story

Comment: @TimWilliams Right! On the [M8](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/connecteurs-circulaires-industriels/1345717) the 4 pins aren't in the right pattern, but on the [M12](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/fr/sal-m12-x-1-4-broches-2-m-coupleur-de-c-ble-sal12-rk42-p136942.html?&trstct=pol_28&nbc=1) they are.

Comment: but the M12 diameter is to small, so it could be the M16 instead

Comment: Aha! This looks like it according to someone who tried iti http://www.exceedconn.com/e_products_detail_home.asp?id=76

Comment: @bobflux Be wary of quack manufacturers claiming IP68 class. That's a custom class for underwater use, which can't be true for these. The second digit only means "better and better" up to IP66. The 67, 68 and 69 classes are all for special purposes. Someone who actually knows what they are talking about and has actually designed an IP68 connector would label it IP66/IP68 or some such. Also, I wouldn't want to use something labelled "N", "L", "Ground" under water if I could avoid it... I would advise to go with some more well-known manufacturer overall.

Comment: Anyway, without knowing the measurements it really does look like a 4 pin M12, A coded. Please note that there are M12 connectors with M16 nut/housing. A lot of these should be available from TE or Phoenix etc.

Comment: @Lundin I'm going to put the inverter indoors, so no problem with dodgy IP class. The connector is only for RS485, not high voltage. I found it on ebay and ordered it.

Answer (score 1):

I identified the connector:

[Exceedcon EC04681-2014-BF](http://www.exceedconn.com/e_products_detail_home.asp?id=76)

It is available on ebay by searching the above reference.